# How to make side menu using browse fragment like netflix in android tv?

Tags: java, android, leanback

[Attached screenshot of netflix app with left side menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHnZL.png) I am able to develop a side menu with customized icon and header in it. I want, when the focus comes on header fragment it should expand on top of row fragment, that is not collapsing the row fragment, the same as Netflix and hotstar are doing. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Will you share a screenshot of the side menu?

Comment: Hi dasser, i edited my question and added a screenshot for your reference.

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Does anybody found any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately, the `HeaderSupportFragment` used in the `BrowseSupportFragment` is not configurable enough to achieve this kind of design. `Leanback` is great to build quickly and easily media browser app but when it comes to "complex" design, it's easier to use custom component.

The major difference also here, is that the left menu of the `BrowseSupportFragment` show each rows header name displayed in the screen (that's why it's called `HeaderSupportFragment`). Here you want to show different entries like search, home, settings, etc.

To make this kind of view, I would suggest creating your own custom view and use a basic `Fragment`. I followed this tutorial which can be useful to handle menu open/close animation (I mixed it with a `ConstraintLayout` to simplify the animation and I made the menu overlap the rest of the screen instead of moving everything.)

See the tutorial: https://medium.com/building-for-android-tv/building-for-android-tv-episode-3-381e041dfec7

Comment: can you give a clue of how did you build the animation to overlap the rest of the screen instead of moving everything? Thanks

Comment: @blueware use ``Activity/Fragment`` to wrap a ``RowSupportFragment``

Comment: @Sofiane Hassaini  The medium link is invalid now. If you have any sample projects please share the GitHub link.

Comment: @blueware by using a `ConstraintLayout`, if you give to the left view (so the menu) a constraint on its start but nothing on its end and just update the width of the menu when you want to open it and it will overlaps the rest of the screen instead of moving the view on the right. I highly recommend to test it with simple 2 views before trying to implement the menu, the rows, etc.

Comment: @MdImranChoudhury unfortunately, I don't have any open source project to share :(
I could take times to write a quick tutorial on this subject and share with you if you are interested

Comment: If possible please share, it will really helpful for us.